# How can I fix this self scroll up effect of the scrollbar that appeared from "nowhere"?

Tags: css, responsive-design, scrollbar, responsive

Recently I was trying to make my page responsive for smartphones, this page displays correctly on computers:

[image]

But when it comes to smartphones I ended up getting some kind of "self scroll up effect" that just doesn't let the user see the content at the bottom of the page:

[image]

Below I will share the respective html and CSS code of this page, I think the solution should be applied within the  `@media (min-width: 270px) and (min-height: 580px) and (max-width: 414px) and (max-height: 812px)` section, but I have tried everything so far to understand why this bug is appearing, yet all my efforts went in vain, so if someone could assist me I would appreciate it, it's just the last thing I need to make my website functional :)

### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Goals</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="goalsstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="s">
        <a href="index.html">Return to Index<i class="fas fa-hand-point-left"></i></a>
    </div>
    <script>
        function createSquare(){
            const section = document.querySelector('section');
            const square = document.createElement('span');

            var size = Math.random()*60;

            square.style.width = 30+size+'px';
            square.style.height = 30+size+'px';

            square.style.top = Math.random()*innerHeight+'px';
            square.style.left = Math.random()*innerWidth+'px';

            section.appendChild(square);
      
            setTimeout(() =>{
                   square.remove()
            },1480)
       }
       setInterval(createSquare , 150)
    </script>
    <section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="imgBx">
              <img src="secretlogo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h2>sCOP</h2>
                <p>To develop a <a href="https://build.scrt.network/dev/secret-contracts.html" style="color: #ffffff" target="_blank">Secret Smart Contract</a> which mints a stablecoin pegged to the value of the Colombian Peso to allow local investors allocate portions of their portfolios to it instead of having to cash them out on centralized exchanges such as Binance.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="imgBx">
            <img src="Chainlink.png" width="600" height="600">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h2 style="font-size:19px;">Provably Secure Gaming Application</h2>
            <p>To build a provably secure gaming application with <a href="https://chain.link/solutions/chainlink-vrf" style="color: #2A79FF" target="_blank">Chainlink VRF</a> that allows users to spend LINK tokens to play an arcade-like game which would reward them with a Dynamic NFT if they win, such Dynamic NFTs could be traded freely on the market.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    <div class="card">
          <div class="imgBx">
              <img src="Elon Mask NFT.png" width="445" height="600">
          </div>
          <div class="content">
              <h2 style="font-size:19px;">Private Meme Coin</h2>
              <p>To develop a private meme coin based on and launch it into the market just for fun, depending on the success and its community, to add new innovative features (such as lending/borrowing, for instance) to make it more valuable and would be a must.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <h3>Noah Verner</h3>
    <header></header>
    <main>
      <article></article>
      <aside></aside>
    </main>
    <footer>Made by NOAH VERNER</footer>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vanilla-tilt.js"></script>
    <script>VanillaTilt.init(document.querySelectorAll(".card"),{max: 19, speed: 400});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    src: url(Fonts/InputSerifCondensed-Regular.ttf);
    font-family: InputSerif;
}


* {
    font-family: InputSerif;
}

body {
    background-color: #F5DC00;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    
}

section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
   
   
}

.container .card{
    position: relative;
    width: 430px;
    height: 620px;
    margin: 150px 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}

.container .card .content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
} 

.container .card .content h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}

.container .card .content p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
}



.container .card .imgBx {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 120px;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 30px;
}

.container .card. .imgBx img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}


span {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: #000;
    animation: animate 2s infinite running; 
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%  {transform: scale(0) translateY(0) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1;}
    10% {opacity: 1;}
    45% {opacity: 1;}
    85% {opacity: 0;}
    100%{transform: scale(1.5) translateY(-1200%) rotate(445deg); opacity: 0;}
}

h3 {
    position: fixed;
    top: -20px ;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    
}

/*Barra de iconos de redes sociales*/

.s {
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    left: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translate(-82.5%);

}

.s a {
    color: #F5DC00;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: 1s;
    transition-property: transform;
}
.s a:hover {
    transform: translate(200px, 0);
}
.s i {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.s a:nth-child(1) i {
    color: #F5DC00;
}

@media (min-width: 270px) and (min-height: 580px) and (max-width: 414px) and (max-height: 812px) {

    .s {
        position: absolute;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        left: 0;
        flex-direction: column;
        transform: translate(-82.5%);
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .s a {
        color: #F5DC00;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        margin: 2px;
        padding: 8px;
        width: 250px;
        text-align: right;
        border-radius: 50px;
        transition: 1s;
        transition-property: transform;
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
        left: 8px;
        display: flex;
        max-width: 330px;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .container .card {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 250px;
        margin: 5px;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border-radius: 15px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        bakcdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    }

    .container .card .content h2 {
        position: fixed;
        top: 90px;
        font-size: 9px !important;
    }

    .container .card .content p {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        font-size: 10.2px;
    }

    .container .card .imgBx {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 80px;
        transform: scale(0.12);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 30px;
    }

    .container .card. .imgBx img {
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 20px;
    }
    
    footer {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations:

First the problem posed in the question. The body has overflow-hidden. If that is removed then the content is scrollable on e.g. the Galaxy emulator on Chrome. You need to check this does not affect the larger screen sizes.

The media query does not reset anything for really narrow viewports (even if the user is unlikely to have a device with very narrow screen, anyone can set the viewport to be what they like on a windows machine so you may want to cater for that).

Your animation consumes large amounts of the GPU on my (quite high-spec) laptop - over 65%. This not only sets the fan whirring which is annoying, it will start to eat a user's smartphone battery. You might like to look into implementing the animation a different way (a different question from the one asked I realize!)

Comment: I see sir, I just deleted the overflow property from the <body> but this only solved the problem partially, because it DOES let the user scroll down to see the content at the bottom of the page, but after several seconds have passed the bug reappears and scrolls up to the top smoothly. I will take a look at the animation, sure, that's easy to change :)

Comment: You need to look at what your animation is doing to the whole thing.